# Filter Nginx logs as per user-agent

Tags: security, nginx, logging

One of my site was hacked recently. I need to filter its Nginx logs by matching specific user-agent. Is there any tool which can help me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `grep USERAGENT /path/to/logfile.log`?

If you investigate the `grep` command by typing `man grep` you will see more options that could expand your findings (adding lines around the one found).
However, if you are using windows, [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490907(v=technet.10)) should help you out, however I personally am not used to the command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish, I could vote. But don't have enough repo.

Comment: No worries mate. If it works out for you, just accept the answer. Otherwise, care to leave a comment :)